# Criar nova base de dados a partir de valores aleatórios com loop ou outro método

Tags: r

Eu tenho três dataframes com número diferente de linhas e eu gostaria de criar um novo dataframe com 100 valores aleatórios a partir desses dataframes e com base em três critérios:

- A - Coluna a e b terá 100 valores aleatórios do 1 dataframe
- B - As primeiras 50 linhas das colunas c1 e d1 em 50 valores aleatórios pareados, ou seja, que ocorrem na mesma linha do dataframe 2
- C - As subsequentes 50 linhas de colunas (51-100) c2 e d2 em outros 50 valores aleatórios pareados, que ocorrem na mesma linha a partir do dataframe 3

Eu tentei com loop, mas não vai bem. Como eu poderia corrigir ou fazer isso de uma forma melhor?

Aqui estão os dados eo script, eo resultado esperado:

```
a <- c(4,6,7,3,2,5,6,9,6,5,8,6,7,8,9,7,6)
b <- c(40,60,70,30,20,NA,60,90,60,50,75,34,42,32,NA,45,29)

c1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
d1 <- c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)

c2 <- c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
d2 <- c(20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11)

df1 <- data.frame(a,b)
df2 <- data.frame(c1,d1)
df3 <- data.frame(c2,d2)

#newdf (with 100 rows)

n <- 100
newdf <- data.frame(n=rep(1:n))
newdf$a <- NA 
newdf$b <- NA 
newdf$c <- NA
newdf$d<- NA

for (i in 1:50){
  newdf$a[i] <- sample(df1$a, 1, replace=T) # random value
  newdf$b[i] <- sample(df1$b, 1, replace=T) # random value 
  newdf$c[i] <- sample[df2$c1,1, replace=T] # one criterion
  newdf$d[i] <- sample[df2$d1,1, replace=T] # one criterion
}

for (i in 51:100){
  newdf$a[i] <- sample(df1$a, 1, replace=T) # random value
  newdf$b[i] <- sample(df1$b, 1, replace=T) # random value 
  newdf$c[i] <- sample[df3$c2,1, replace=T] # two criterion
  newdf$d[i] <- sample[df3$d2,1, replace=T] #two criterion
}

#Result 

a      b     c    d 
7     60     1    10 # linha 1
6     50     3    8
2     90     5    6  # linha 50
.
.
.
2     90     11    20  # linha 51
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que a melhor maneira para resolver este problema não seja através de um loop. Eu resolvi ele selecionando as linhas aleatoriamente, todas de uma vez. Guardei estes resultados dentro de vetores chamadas `index_a`, `index_b`, `index_cd_50` e `index_cd_100`. Estes vetores armazenam, portanto, as 100 linhas sorteadas do df1, com as colunas a e b, e as 50 linhas sorteadas dos df2 e 50 linhas sorteadas do df3.

Estas linhas serão consideradas antes ou depois da posição 50 quando monto o newdf. Tente rodar o código linha a linha para identificar o que fiz.

```
a <- c(4,6,7,3,2,5,6,9,6,5,8,6,7,8,9,7,6)
b <- c(40,60,70,30,20,NA,60,90,60,50,75,34,42,32,NA,45,29)

c1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
d1 <- c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)

c2 <- c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
d2 <- c(20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11)

df1 <- data.frame(a,b)
df2 <- data.frame(c1,d1)
df3 <- data.frame(c2,d2)

index_a <- sample(1:nrow(df1), 100, replace=TRUE)
index_b <- sample(1:nrow(df1), 100, replace=TRUE)

index_cd_50  <- sample(1:nrow(df2), 50, replace=TRUE)

index_cd_100 <- sample(1:nrow(df3), 50, replace=TRUE)

newdf <- data.frame(a=df1$a[index_a],
                    b=df1$b[index_b],
                    c=c(df2$c1[index_cd_50], df2$d1[index_cd_100]),
                    d=c(df3$c2[index_cd_50], df3$d2[index_cd_100]))
```